# Sync web directories over multiple servers on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, synchronization, amazon-elb

Lets say I have 3 servers, One is a development server, prototype code goes here. When it's done I've been using scp to push that file to the live server but now I'm looking into multiple live server setups and Amazon load balancer.

How do I go about syncing these two live servers. I've looked up a little about rsync, would that be the easiest to set up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep load-balanced servers synced even with deleted files?](http://serverfault.com/questions/304142/how-to-keep-load-balanced-servers-synced-even-with-deleted-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to use some kind of deploy tool to run the deploys for you. This way it will run the same commands on each server. I recommend

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/index.html

That is great if you know python. If you are a ruby person then I'd look at

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/

You could do rsync but if you deploys ever get complicated it might be easier to start with fabric or capistrano

Comment: Will look into those now, thanks for the fast response